# type double computation always results in 1.0 or 0.0

Tags: java

```
            double dominantAtk = 1 - (WarriorFormulas.calculateDefence(victim, attacker) + 2) / (2 * (WarriorFormulas.calculateAttack(attacker,victim) + 1));
        double dominantDef = (MeleeFormulas.calculateAttack(attacker, victim) / (2 * (MeleeFormulas.calculateDefence(victim, attacker) + 1)));
```

Both calculateDefence and calculateAttack return high numbers, No matter what the number is, it always results in 1.0 or 0.0.

the computation itself.

On higher attack roll:
Accuracy = 1 - (Def+2) / [2*(Atk+1)]

On higher Def roll:
Accuracy = (Atk) / [2*(Def+1)]

Comment: ***So many duplicates...***

Comment: You are dividing with an integer, an integer division always result int an integer, try casting the denominator to a double